# how to save session value and pass it from one function of controller to another function

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, routes

Sending a value from one function of my controller 'login_user' to another function 'dashboard' the value is saved in a session but i cant access the value when i'm using the uri routing to get it here is the code

```
public function login_user(){
    //$cache=$this->input->post();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $this->load->model('Pmodel');
        $login_data=$this->Pmodel->login_model($email,$password);
        print_r($login_data);
        if($login_data){
            $data= $this->session->set_userdata('data', $login_data );
            var_dump($data);   
            return redirect(base_url()."user/dashboard".$data);
            //$this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard',['data'=>$data]);
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('Login_failed','Invalid Username/Password.');
            return redirect('user/login_invalid');
            //echo "string";
        }
    }else{      
        return redirect('user/login_invalid');
    }
}
```

And another function

```
public function dashboard(){    
    if ($this->session->userdata('data') === NULL){
        echo "hello";
        return redirect('user/login_invalid');
    }else{
        $login_data = $this->uri->segment(3); 
        var_dump($login_data);
        $this->load->model('Pmodel');
        $email=$this->Pmodel->select_model('$email');
        $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard',$email);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load session library for this if isn't active yet

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

For set session use this

```
$this->session->set_userdata('session_name', 'data');
```

For retrieve user data use this

```
$this->session->userdata('rec_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call below function instead of redirection if both functions "login_user" and "dashboard" are in same controller.

```
$data= $this->session->set_userdata('data', $login_data );
var_dump($data);   
return redirect(base_url()."user/dashboard".$data);
```

Replace above redirection with simple class function call with:

```
$data= $this->session->set_userdata('data', $login_data );
$this->dashboard($data);
```

The dashboard function body may look like this now.

```
function dashboard($data=null){
  // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying it for hours i finally found a way to pass the value from one controller to another here is the code

```
$this->session->set_userdata( $login_data );

        $data=$this->session->all_userdata($login_data);

        return redirect(base_url()."user/dashboard/?data=".json_encode($data));
```

Now on the dashboard function just use this to get the data

```
 $data=json_decode($_GET['data']);
  $this->load->model('Pmodel'); 
 $email['data']=$this->Pmodel->select_model($data);
   $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard',$email);
```

this would pass the data in your model and you are done .